# Path-dependent types vs. "underlying types", which ones are checked?

Tags: reflection, scala, type-systems, path-dependent-type, abstract-type

When using path-dependent types with reflection I am getting a type mismatch error even though I have matching "underlying types". What are these "non-underlying types" and why are they checked instead of the "underlying types"?

In the code below, I want the `compare` method to accept only same-type subclasses of A as arguments. The error is on the last line.

```
abstract class A(val a:Int) {
  type Impl <: A
  def compare(other:Impl) {
    if(a==other.a) println("equal") else println("diff")
  }
}
class B(a:Int) extends A(a) {type Impl = B}

object Test {
  def newInst(a: Int, className: String) = {
    val constr = Class.forName(className).getConstructors()(0)
    constr.newInstance(a.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]).asInstanceOf[A]
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val b1 = newInst(4, "B")
    val b2 = newInst(5, "B")
    b1.compare(b2)   // type mismatch error here
  }
}
```

On the last line I get this error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : b2.type (with underlying type A)
required: b1.Impl
```

Since the type of b2 is the same as the type of b1 (which is A), I expected this to not generate an error. For some reason these path-dependent types are different than the "underlying types" when using reflection. Why?

If I do not use reflection, it works:

```
val b1 = new B(4)
val b2 = new B(5)
b1.compare(b2)  // no errors
```

(I do need to use reflection in my case). Can `newInst()` return the object as class "B",  using reflection? Would this help? Is there type erasure when using abstract types?

This is the only reference I found ([on this forum](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Confusing-type-error-found-X-required-X-td1934680.html)) about the same error, but it may not be related.

Comment: Thank you for asking! It was really strange and took me a day to find a workaround and finally saw your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with reflection. The type of `b1` and `b2` is `A` (since that's the return type of `newInst`). For call `b1.compare(b2)` to compile, `b2` must have type `b1.Impl`. The compiler knows only that it is some subtype of `A`, but it doesn't know which one. Since you can't pass an `A` where some subtype of `A` is required, you get an error.

In the example

```
val b1 = new B(4)
val b2 = new B(5)
b1.compare(b2)  // no errors
```

both variables have type `B`, and `B#Impl` is `B`, so everything typechecks.

Comment: I just figured that out too. The expression "underlying type" is a bit misleading, while it actually means "parent type". Ideally I would like to cast the return type of newInst to the class of "className" but that looks like it is not possible in Scala.

Answer (score 5):

> I just figured that out too. The
>   expression "underlying type" is a bit
>   misleading, while it actually means
>   "parent type". Ideally I would like to
>   cast the return type of newInst to the
>   class of "className" but that looks
>   like it is not possible in Scala. "

It does not mean "parent type".  That type does happen to be a parent.  An underlying type refers to the widening of a singleton type.  The type of the number 5 is a singleton; its underlying type is Int.  Most people would not call Int the "parent type".  (Even though, again, it is.)

As to the question, you can just cast it.  Nothing will stand in your way: scala won't and java can't.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val b1 = newInst(4, "B")
  val b2 = newInst(5, "B")
  b1.compare(b2.asInstanceOf[b1.Impl])
}
% scala Test
diff
```

Comment: What I meant is to cast the return value before it is returned, inside newInst(). Since I don't have the type available (I only have the Class), I don't see a way to do it. If that would be possible, the type checker would be able to infer the type of newInst() at compile time, based on a runtime value (className) - that of course is not possible. I think this also clarifies the meaning of "underlying type". It is the most specific type known at compile time, while the runtime type is known only as object.type    I'm not sure what you mean by "widening a singleton". b2 is not a singleton.

Comment: b2 is absolutely a singleton.  What do you think "b2.type" means? It is the type of b2.  Not the type of b1, b3, or anything else in the world.  And its underlying type, what it is an instance of, is A.

Comment: b2 is an instance of B, cast to A. It is not a singleton, which in my book (PinS) is an object defined with the 'object' keyword. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing much of the type system, which is built around singleton types.  The 'object' keyword defines a class with a single instance.  The type of the object is a singleton type.  But many other things have singleton types.  Anytime you use a path to refer to a type (like "b2.Impl") the prefixes must be stable.  I refer you to the specification where all this is explained in great detail.

Comment: Learning the hard way is still called learning, right? Thanks, @extempore